# Dimension of Affine Scheme of Integral Domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have a question about an argument in the proof of prop. 8.4 in Bosch's "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" (see page 376): Following statement is used:

Let $A$ be a $k$ algebra of finite type and an integal domain. Consider $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ the corresponding affine scheme.
Let $x \in X$ arbitrary.

We define $\dim_x X:= \inf\limits _{\substack{U \subset X \text{ open, }\\ x \in U}}\!\! \dim U$

Why does

$$\dim_x X = \dim U$$

hold for every open subset $U \subset X$?

Especially why the inequality $\dim_x X \ge \dim U$?

In the book he argues firstly that every closed point of a open non empty subscheme $U \subset X$ is dense in $X$. But for example if we take $U=X$ and $x$ arbitrary closed point of $X$ then thats of course highly wrong.

Furthermore it should follow from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. How?

Could anybody explain to me the argument given about to settle $\dim_x X = \dim U$?

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be finite type over a field?

Comment: @asdq: Yes, thank you for remark, $A$ is supposed as a $k$ algebra of finite type. I modified my question.

Comment: The inequality holds because the dimension of $X$ at $x$ is the*infimum* of the dimensions of all open $U$ which contain $x$.

Comment: "In the book he argues firstly that every closed point of a open non empty subscheme U⊂X is dense in X" Are you sure that is really what is written?

Comment: @Bernard: I think that your argument provides only the trivial inequility $\dim_x X \le \dim U$. Or did I misunderstood your argument?

Comment: You're correct, but the equality is not in the definition, which the formulation of your question leads to think.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a finite type $k$-algebra for any field $k$ and $A$ is furthermore a domain, then if $U$ is any non empty open subset of $\operatorname{Spec} A$, we have $\dim U=\dim A$. This essentially follows from the fact that $\dim A=\operatorname{tr.deg}_k\operatorname{Frac}A$ holds. Since $U$ contains a principal open which is itself the spectrum of a domain of finite type over $k$ that has the same field of fractions as $A$, the equality follows, together with the fact that we always have $\dim U\leq \dim A$ for any open subset $U$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. One point stays unclear: Do you see in which way Bosch uses here the Nullstellensatz? I don't see how it really incorporates in the proof.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't see it either.